# 502, Bad Gateway, I've set wordpress rest api using express-http-proxy

Tags: node.js, express, http-proxy

I have problem with bad gateway issue.

I'm using express-http-proxy(https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy)

And I set wordpress REST API Address. But It doesn't works for me.

```
app.use(
    '/api', 
    proxy('https://shawnbaek.com/wp-json/wp/v2/', {
        proxyReqOptDecorator(opts) {
            opts.headers['x-forwarded-host'] = 'localhost:3000';
            return opts;
        }
    })
);
```

Anyone knows this problem?

Comment: have you tried dissecting it a little and see which part causes the issue? for example does hitting https://shawnbaek.com/wp-json/wp/v2/ directly with an HTTP client work? then try to use an HTTP client within your route handler (such as [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)) in place of `express-http-proxy` to compose your API proxy and see if it works (this way you also gain a bit more visibility and flexibility).